# 503 Error ObjectifyService NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

### UPDATE

If I remove the `@Cache` annotation on profile pojo it works on dev environment.

---

### ORIGINAL

My issue is that in GAE dev server with intellij I´m getting this error when I'm trying to create a key from de userId with objectify

**On api explorer**

```
503 Service Unavailable

{
 "error": {
  "message": "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE",
  "code": 503,
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

**Java exception**

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory.stringToKey(KeyFactory.java:194)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.KeyMemcacheService.keyify(KeyMemcacheService.java:46)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.KeyMemcacheService.getIdentifiables(KeyMemcacheService.java:76)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache.getAll(EntityMemcache.java:245)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService.get(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:252)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine.fetch(LoadEngine.java:168)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round.fetchPending(Round.java:168)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round.execute(Round.java:137)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine.execute(LoadEngine.java:89)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:70)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.LoadResult.now(LoadResult.java:25)
```

Also, deployed on app engine I don have any problem, it just works fine. I have tried on chrome and firefox.

My code is like this

**OfyService.java**

```
static {
        try {
            factory().register(Profile.class);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }


    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

**Profile.java**

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class Profile {
    String userName;
    String displayName;
    String mainEmail;

    @Id String userId;

    public Profile(String userId, String userName, String displayName, String mainEmail) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.mainEmail = mainEmail;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public String getMainEmail() {
        return mainEmail;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    private Profile() {
    }

    public void update(String userName, String displayName, String mainEmail) {
        if (userName != null) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        if (displayName != null) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }
        if (mainEmail != null) {
            this.mainEmail = mainEmail;
        }
    }

    public void updateName(String displayName) {
        if (displayName != null) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }
    }
}
```

**MyApi.java**

```
//region Profile
    @ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public Profile saveProfile(final User user, ProfileForm profileForm)
            throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization required");
        }
        String mainEmail = user.getEmail();
        String userId = user.getUserId();
        String displayName = profileForm.getDisplayName();

        Key<Profile> profileKey = Key.create(Profile.class, userId);
        Profile profile = ofy().load().key(profileKey).now();

        String userName = extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(mainEmail);
        if (profile == null) {
        ...
```

**At this line**

```
Profile profile = ofy().load().key(profileKey).now();
```

I'm using this versions (and tried whit other version to):

- appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.53
- appengine-endpoints:1.9.53
- guava:22.0-android
- objectify:5.1.16

And this others versions:

- jdk: 1.8.0_121
- intellij 2017.1.3
- Google Cloud SDK 156.0.0

  - app-engine-java 1.9.53
  - app-engine-python 1.9.53
  - bq 2.0.24
  - cloud-datastore-emulator 1.2.1
  - core 2017.05.19
  - gcloud
  - gsutil 4.26

Answer (score 0):

This [error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldError.html)  is thrown if an application tries to access or modify a specified field of an object, and that object no longer has that field or also changed (in general partially compiled or same class in other depending project).
Try to identify the class in occurence all classes where that field came from before the change and update all your project, and simple clean and build will do the trick even if usually modern IDE will do this for you.

Comment: Can you explain in other word this "Try to identify the class in occurence all classes where that field came from before the change"

Comment: @Niesteszeck that was a field of a class, try to know in which class that field was